# Reprompt input after incorrect plug in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, input, python-3.3

How can one reprompt this this input if the input is anything other than 1 or 2?

```
status = eval(input("Are they single(1) or married(2)? \n"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
while True:
    status = input("Are they single(1) or married(2)? \n")
    if status in ('1', '2'):
        break
```

BTW, don't use `eval`. It can evaluate arbitrary expression. If you want convert the input string to int, use [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) instead.

Comment: In this case, converting to `int` means you'll possibly raise an exception. Better to just leave as `str`

Answer (score 0):

@falsetru, has answered with my preferred way already. Here is a couple of alternatives you may see elsewhere

```
status = input("Are they single(1) or married(2)? \n")
while status not in ('1', '2'):
    status = input("Are they single(1) or married(2)? \n")
```

This is not desirable due to the duplication of the prompt

```
status = -1 # or 0 or None or some other invalid value
while status not in ('1', '2'):
    status = input("Are they single(1) or married(2)? \n")
```

This is just ugly in my opinion, but some people dislike using `break`

One reason I prefer @falsetru's version is that it's easy to convert for a `for` loop when you want to count/limit the number of retries.